# Android SecurityException Permission denial READ_SMS

Tags: android, permissions

I am actually working on a simple app, that reads the sms from the phone and later sends one of them to another phone.

That for I've recreated [this project](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qw7YLJWFHIQ&spfreload=10) in Android Studio. The code has no errors of anything like that, but if I launch it my logical puts out the following warning:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException:
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.fetchinboxsms/
com.example.android.fetchinboxsms.MainActivity}:
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: 
opening provider com.android.providers.telephony.SmsProvider from 
ProcessRecord{ebd2075 2443:com.example.android.fetchinboxsms/u0a59} (pid=2443, uid=10059) 
requires android.permission.READ_SMS or android.permission.WRITE_SMS
```

I've given `READ_SMS` permission in the Manifest file, so why does this error occur? Any suggestions?

Comment: please post your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: I have a strong feeling you are experiencing the same issues as I have described here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32814922/why-does-android-ignore-read-sms-permission/32846384#32846384

Fix your app to support Android M permission model